# Re-Installation of SharePoint Search Express in SharePoint Foundation

Tags: search, sharepoint-foundation

I have installed the SharePoint Foundation in production server using standalone configuration.
at that time I faced a problem of port 80. There was no configuration asked from the SharePoint but SharePoint was installed and started using port-80. Now my other sites that was running on port-80 was stopped dramatically. After checking in IIS I found the "Default Website" was stopped.

Now it was urgent to resolve the issue. I did a little bit search and found a solution that I need extend the web application from central admin and use port 79 instead of 80. After the new will started working, remove the port-80 site of SharePoint from IIS and use port-79 site.
I did the same given. My problem was resolved.

**Now The Problem is :**
After one day, I was installing the **Search Server Express**. The Search Server Express was installed successfully but while running configuration wizard I got an error of about not having SharePoint Site on port-80. The error was asking me about to create a site on port-80 instead of site running on port-79 as a Default Site.
Next step I have tried was again run setup of **search Server Express**. Here there was two option i.e. to remove or to repair the setup. I selected the repair option. Here I got the error **unable to repair the Search Server express. Please check the log file.**

**Now I need:**
How to install/re-install the or configure the Search server express on foundation? so it should start working.
Which step is missed, I am facing problem in install?

**I cant do:**
I cant uninstall the SharePoint Foundation. As my site is deployed.
I cant use port-80 because other applications are working/running on port-80.

Please help me soon.
Thanks in Advance.
- Khan Abubakar.